# JQuery Fixed Scrolling issue in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, scroll, css-position

I'm trying to make this .side_content_wrapper become fixed or static based on how far the user has scrolled down the page and back up it. I have it working fine in IE8+/chrome/firefox. But for some reason I can't get it to work in IE7. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help!

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){

var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
var heightFromBottom = documentHeight - scrollAmount;
$el = $('.side_content_wrapper'); 

if((scrollAmount > 320 && heightFromBottom > 950) && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
    fixToScroll();}

else if (scrollAmount < 320 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
    fixToStatic();}

if(heightFromBottom <= 950 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
    fixToBottom();} 

else if((heightFromBottom > 950 && scrollAmount > 320) && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
    fixToScroll();}


function fixToScroll() { 
    $('.side_content_wrapper').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '35px', 'right': '218px'});
}
function fixToStatic() { 
    $('.side_content_wrapper').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px', 'right': '0px'}); 
}
function fixToBottom() { 
    $('.side_content_wrapper').css({'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': '400px', 'top': 'inherit', 'right': '218px'}); 
}
});
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? The scroll distance detection or the position change? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I tried debugging with IE Developer tools and I get no errors. I think I have some syntax wrong somewhere that IE isn't reading correctly. It doesn't detect the distance until I get to the bottom of the page and then it changes the position.

Comment: Check your document mode to make sure you are in IE7 standards (and not quirks mode or compatibility mode or any other silly thing MS decided to throw in there). I have read that `position: fixed` was a little buggy in IE7 depending on what mode the browser is in.

Comment: Yea, its in ie IE7 standards :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $('.fixed_floater');
    var offset = div.offset();
    var top = offset.top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var heightFromBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y >= top && heightFromBottom > 950) {
            div.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
        } else {
            div.css({'position': 'static'});
        }

        if (heightFromBottom <= 950)
            div.css({'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': '390px', 'top': 'auto'});
    });
});
```